# Angular is not recognized inside my user control

Tags: asp.net, .net, angularjs

I am using Angular inside my .NET app in VS2015. Everything works fine when inside my main page, I am also using various panels to display my data. So lets say that I have a controller named `MainCtrl` and is declared as such inside my Homepage.aspx

```
<div class="panel panel-default" data-ng-app="APP">                    
 <div class="panel-body" data-ng-controller="MainController">
  <asp:Panel ID="PanelTest" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
 </div>
</div>
```

this controller has a variable named `testmessage="Hello"` and if I have `{{testmessage}}` inside my panels code then it displays, as it should, `Hello`. If I dont declare my controller in Homepage.aspx though, and instead declare it inside my user control just above the place where `{{testmessage}}` is located then it's as if angular is not recognized anymore and what I see in my rendered page is {{testmessage}} and not Hello.

Why is this, should I follow some other steps for declaring my various angular controllers inside a user control .ascx and ascx.cs?

After investigating a little bit it became clear that this is because all Javascript files that I include in my controller are loaded just above that controller, but angular and my APP declaration is done at the bottom of my `body` element.

Is there anything else I could do except from moving all my JavaScript declarations to my header?

Comment: Angular is a clientside technology and doesn't care / know about your asp markup.  All that matters is the HTML which is output when you process the webpage.  So I'd look at the HTML which is output rather than what the server is doing.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP. Please retag.

Comment: @Paul for some reason at the time SO's css would not load up, so it was hard to see, I must have accidentally confused them.